# Shell Scripting - how to print the file names with a specific pattern modified in the last 10 minutes

Tags: shell, unix

```
find . -name 'abc*.log' -exec grep -il 'bad password' {} \;
```

This command gets me the file names with the pattern abc*.log and has the key word 'bad password'.
How do I include the requirement of the files being modified with in the last 10 minutes should only be displayed? I need only one line command.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-mmin -10` should do the trick.

`find . -name 'abc*.log' -mmin -10 -exec grep -il 'bad password' {} \;`